# Get all the bytes from networkstream.Read into single byte array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a TCP server (a line scan camera) which based on specifications sends me the image data. The image data is in form of 1D byte array. The number of bytes sent by the camera is known but it can vary based on the specification so sometimes it will be a very large number and sometimes a small one. I am using Networkstream.Read to get the bytes and trying to store it into an array.

The problem is that it sends me in packets. I need a way that all the data sent from the stream is stored in a single byte array which I can then use and convert it to an image.

This is the code I have been using now. I am still new to VB. I tried storing the data into arrays and then append them but somehow VB does not provide that functionality.

```
        Dim imageData(numberOfColumns * numberOfLines - 1) As Byte
        Dim bytesReceived = 
        Dim bytesReceivedTotal = 0
        Dim bytesToRcv = numberOfColumns * numberOfLines
        Dim imageFragment() As Byte
        Dim rcvbytes(8092) As Byte 'tried socket.receivebuffersize too
        Dim readCount = 0

        Do
            bytesReceived = clientStream.Read(rcvbytes, 0, rcvbytes.Length) 
            bytesReceivedTotal += bytesReceived
            rcvbytes.CopyTo(imageData, (bytesReceivedTotal - bytesReceived))
        Loop Until bytesReceivedTotal = bytesToRcv
```

The problem with this code is that the length of the rcvbytes does not change for the last read. Is there a way that I can store all the data from the stream in a single byte array? the size of the bytes sent by the server is obtained by: (numberOfLines * numberOfColumns)

UPDATE #2: WORKING CODE

```
            Do
            Dim bytesWanted As Integer = bytesReceivedTotal + 8092
            Dim bytesToRead As Integer = If(bytesWanted > imageData.Length, imageData.Length - bytesReceivedTotal, 8092)


            bytesReceived = clientStream.Read(imageData, bytesReceivedTotal, bytesToRead)
            bytesReceivedTotal += bytesReceived
        Loop Until bytesReceivedTotal = bytesToRcv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TCP is a stream-based protocol, the only way to surely put all expected data (an entire "message") into a single array is to keep calling `NetworkStream.Read()` until you've read the sufficient amount of bytes.

> I tried storing the data into arrays and then append them but somehow VB does not provide that functionality.

That is not true. There are several ways you can concatenate chunks of data. You could for instance use a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

However in your case the answer is actually right under your nose. If you take a look at the [**`NetworkStream.Read()` documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that the second parameter (called `offset`) specifies *"The location in `buffer` to begin storing the data to"* - where `buffer` is the byte array you specify as the first parameter.

If you give the `offset` parameter the number of already read bytes it will append the new bytes after the already received ones, in the array. Also keep in mind that you do not want to read too much if you're getting close to the end of the array.

```
Dim bytesWanted As Integer = bytesReceivedTotal + 8092
Dim bytesToRead As Integer = If(bytesWanted > imageData.Length, imageData.Length - bytesReceivedTotal, 8092)

clientStream.Read(imageData, bytesReceivedTotal, bytesToRead)
```

Comment: I did it using another method few minutes ago but your code totally makes sense. The way I did is using memory stream to write the data to from the buffer and it works. Which one is more preferable though?

PS: I can't seem to paste the code properly. First time using stackoverflow

Comment: @ShamsRKhan : My code consumes less memory than yours, since using a `MemoryStream` both stores the data you give it as a new copy in memory, but also creates an entirely new array when you call `MemoryStream.ToArray()`, while mine writes to you main array directly (thus it is also a bit faster). -- Also please don't mark it as answer before you've tested it. It is better to verify if it works or not first.

Comment: @ShamsRKhan : Copying code can sometimes be a bit tricky... Just try to select it all by dragging the selection outside the code block.

Comment: @ShamsRKhan : Great! I'm glad I could help! Good luck with your project! :)